# Python Change the time AM to PM and Vice Versa

Tags: python, time, replace, strptime, strftime

I have a list of time. I want all AM to be PM and all PM to AM.

Input
`newtimes`

Output
**['10:31 PM', '10:03 PM', '12:26 AM', '07:40 PM', '09:32 PM']**

Input

```
       for items in newtimes:
       newtimes1 = items.replace('AM','PM').replace('PM','AM')
       print(newtimes1)
```

Output i am getting:
10:31 AM
10:03 AM
12:26 AM
07:40 AM
09:32 AM

Am looking for the output such as:
**10:31 AM

10:03 AM

12:26 PM

07:40 AM

09:32 AM**

Comment: Why are you doing both `.replace()` when the string will only contain either 'AM' or 'PM'? What do you think happens when an AM is present in the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check before you replace:

```
for old_time in old_times:
    if 'AM' in old_time:
        new_time = old_time.replace('AM', 'PM')
    else:
        new_time = old_time.replace('PM', 'AM')
    print(new_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting all string to have PM, then all to AM with your code. Here is an example of code that will work:

```py
times = ['10:31 PM', '10:03 PM', '12:26 AM', '07:40 PM', '09:32 PM']

for i, time in enumerate(times):
  if 'PM' in time:
    times[i] = time.replace('PM', 'AM')
  else:
    times[i] = time.replace('AM', 'PM')
print(times)
```